# Custom arbor.js shapes

Tags: arbor.js

I'm creating html canvas illustrations using a an adobe illustrator plugin. Here is [link to an example](http://jsfiddle.net/makingthings/HzrFG/) The example is an fried egg. As a fun project I'm making an illustrated restaurant menu linking things like eggs, bacon, bread etc.

I'm hopping to use these illustrations within arbor.js Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the best way to work out what's going on with arbor.js is to dive in and read the code, it's really well laid out. Look at [the JavaScript for the sample project](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/blob/master/docs/sample-project/main.js), in particular `particleSystem.eachNode`. You can see how and where the nodes and edges are rendered. For a more thorough version, check out the 'Altas' example - that shows how to do text rendering on the nodes.

Good luck!

Comment: What other info would you like? eachNode is the place you need to put your rendering code.

Comment: The problem is I'm not a very good swimmer. No quite sure where to put the code. i've posted a supplementary question on the subject. James

Comment: No probs, I'm also new to arbor. :) I'm at work, but will take a look later if there are no other helpful responses.